# Trying to fill the diamond I drew on my JavaScript file with a color but it comes back black

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I'm very new to coding and have no idea what I'm doing. I created a diamond in my canvas in the JS file, using the "+c+" but it keeps coming back black. Any help would be much appreciated, it's driving me crazy.

```js
const ctx = document.querySelector("canvas").getContext('2d')
const w = 200
const h = 200

diamond(w / 2, h / 2, 50, 50, 260, 0.5);

function diamond(x, y, w, h, c, a) {
  x = x - w / 2;
  y = y - h / 2;
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(x, y);
  ctx.lineTo(x + w, y + h);
  ctx.lineTo(x, y + h * 2);
  ctx.lineTo(x - w, y + h);
  ctx.lineTo(x, y);
  ctx.fillStyle = "hsal(" + c + ", 100%, 50%, " + a + ")";
  ctx.fill();
}
```

```html
<canvas width="200" height="200"></canvas>
```

Comment: it's `hsl()` not `hsal()`

Comment: @Phil, you scared me, with the code you've updated to...it was almost letter by letter I typed it, just missing ; at the end of lines...thought the code we type here is visible to others before we submit.

Comment: @vanowm I just take OP's code and add bits until it's at least parseable (while trying not to solve the problem in the snippet itself).

Comment: @Phil, yeah, that's what I was doing too, typed exactly the same as you have...

Answer (score 3):

This:

```
ctx.fillStyle = "hsal(" + c + ", 100%, 50%, " + a + ")";
```

Should be changed into:

```
ctx.fillStyle = "hsl(" + c + ", 100%, 50%, " + a + ")";
```

From what I can tell your color doesn't have a value and your diamond shows as black.

Edited as an answer

Comment: that should be `"hsla("`.